# Store multiple XML node values in string using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am trying to store XML response node values to a string.
Response :

```
<ReturnResourceItemResponse>
   <ReturnResourceItemResult>
            <countryID>1</countryID>
            <resourceItemID>2000</resourceItemID>
            <locationID>88</locationID>
            <groupID>518</groupID>            
            <floor>1</floor>            
            <resourceID>1</resourceID>            
            <name>Hello</name>
   </ReturnResourceItemResult>            
</ReturnResourceItemResponse>
```

Result i want :

```
[2000, Hello, 1, 1, 88, 518, 1]
```

What i tried :

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)
def nodes = holder.getDomNodes( "//*:countryID" )
def XMLlist = []
for( node in nodes )
{
  def value = com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.getNodeValue( node )
  XMLlist.add( value)
}
log.info "XML_List =" + XMLlist
```

Result i am getting :

```
XML_List =[1]
```

Comment: It is now a valid xml. Can you provide more valid sample. Does it have items list ?

Comment: I have pasted the exact result i am getting in response. There is no Items list.

Comment: It is clearly wrong, not a well-formed xml.

Comment: Because, start element differs from ending tag. Isn't it? or a typo?

Comment: Raj Negi, any way, added my answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is noticed that OP is using `Script Assertion` for the request step.

Here is the `Script Assertion` which asserts the response and retrieves the data that OP requested.

**Script Assertion**

```
//Retrieves the ReturnResourceItemResult
def getItemResult = { response ->
   def parsedResponse = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
   parsedResponse.'**'.find{it.name() == 'ReturnResourceItemResult' }
}

//Retrieves the data from Item result
def getItemResultData = { itemResult, elements ->
   def result = []
   elements.each { element ->
    result << itemResult.'**'.find{it.name() == element} as String
   }
   result
}

//Assert if result is not empty or null
assert context.response, "Response data is empty or null"

//Defining the element order will have the better control on result order
def list = ['resourceItemID', 'name', 'countryID', 'resourceID', 'locationID', 'groupID', 'floor']

//Jus call the above closures to get the data
def data = getItemResultData(getItemResult(context.response), list)
//Show the result
log.info "Extracted data is :${data}"
```

You may quickly test it from here <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5089288077180928)</kbd>

Note that, had to make the xml well-formed, so changed a bit.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @RajNegi, glad to know that the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the countryId with *

`

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)
def nodes = holder.getDomNodes( "//*:*" )
def XMLlist = []
for( node in nodes )
{
  def value = com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.getNodeValue( node )
  XMLlist.add( value)
}
log.info "XML_List =" + XMLlist
```

`

or you can get all the values from node using

`def nodes = holder.getNodeValues( "//*:*" )`

Comment: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 5 on line 2 in {\n//*:*}: expected "<name>", found "*"